# PDF Where does Acrobat reader save information about last view settings?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I usually check "Restore last view settings" in preferencs of Acrobat Reader. But I'm actually wondering where Acrobat Reader saves this information? In Windows Registry? In PDF file itself? On my local disk?

Comment: I'm not sure where it gets stored, but you might be able to figure it out by using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor the registry and other activity that occurs when running Reader.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it is stored here in the registry:

```
HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\9.0\RememberedViews
```

Comment: a sigh.... ....registry
so there is not way to copy these settings from one computer to another to keep them in sync

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked this yet, but I'm pretty sure it saves the actual recent views in application data. This should be easy to test: look for the acrobat data in %appdata% then copy it to another computer or back it up. If the backup opens pdf to the same place, then that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I checked all appdata and ProgramData folders, but the info is not stored there. I opened

```
HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\9.0\RememberedViews
```

There I found these folders - `c1,c2,c3,...,c15`
In them there were keys like `ipageViewPageNum, ipageViewX, ipageViewY`.
I guessed that `ipageViewPageNum` is the page number at which it opens the document and Adobe Reader saves view settings for 15 PDFs.

I opened many PDFs and scrolled to the same page number before closing Adobe Reader. I found out that the value of ipageViewPageNum changed to that page number everywhere. I also noticed that opening PDFs which were not the 15 most recent opened at the first page. This means my guess was right.