# Why do some pdf/acrobat files not support "previous view"?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have several pdfs that have the "Previous View" (alt-back arrow) option disabled/grayed out.  [I'm not the only one](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/679986?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true) with this unresolved problem.

Does anyone know why and if it's possible to fix the files so the feature is enabled?

Comment: Previous view is taken from HKCU\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\RememberedViews. For each pdf file reader creates a new registry key with iTime and xID subkeys (and with other sub-sub keys that contain information about the previous view). For those files, where you cant go to the previous view xID key is not created. I don't know what is the purpose of this key, but if you can figure out, you will find the root of the problem

Comment: The link provided points to a question on a different issue (the initial view upon opening a document), which is the topic of http://superuser.com/questions/83935/pdf-where-does-acrobat-reader-save-information-about-last-view-settings. An issue with Previous View is mentioned in one of the answers there, specifically about navigation across documents. If this is your case, then part of that answer might apply to you. It would be useful that you clarify this point. Plus, the Acrobat versión might make a difference, so it is useful to quote that too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the 'previous view' doesn't work on some pdf files, but at least there is a simple workaround.
Take the latest version of acrobat reader, click "Save as" -> "PDF..." and use this new file. That should work

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a shot next time I run into this and accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

"Right-click anywhere in the toolbar and choose Page Navigation, then the button(s) you want to add." (Adobe forums)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not that the toolbar button isn't visible.  The problem is that the previous view button/menu item is grayed out and disabled.